# I pressed one cell in UITableViewl using 3D touch, then it prompted wrong cell view

Tags: ios, macos, peek, 3dtouch

In my test demo, I put a UITableView into UIViewController in storyboard. When I test demo on my iPhone, I pressed one cell in tableView, I got this error in picture

[wrong cell view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VZxZ.jpg)

In `func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?` method, I use

`guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location), cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) else { return nil }` to get the pressed cell in UITableView.

I really appreciate if you give me any answers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you register your source view, are you adding the view controller's view or your tableview?  I had a similar issue on a collection view but once I registered the actual view and not the view controller's view, the behavior was corrected.

so in other words..

**This gave me wrong cell**

registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView:self.view)

**This corrected the behavior**

registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView:self.tableView)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have solved this problem by replacing the method of adding UITableView to a UIViewController with UITableViewController